# Can my browsing be monitered if I'm using my own sim card but a different modem?

Tags: mobile

The modem I use was given to me by someone else, and the sim card has a monthly subscription of data.

I use it a lot, but now I've run out of data and I don't have a phone.So I'm using the modem but I'm using my own sim card.

Can my browser history be monitored by an employer even if I'm using my own sim card in their modem?

Comment: Most employers I know of make a statement similar to "you can expect no privacy on a corporate device".  It's not an answer, but it's a good assumption to make.

Answer (score 1):

This is not easy to answer. Assuming you are using a PC with the modem, it is absolutely possible that your employer requires your browsing to go through a proxy server or perhaps a VPN as well. This would ensure that your browsing history is retained by them in an audit log.

The SIM card merely tells the modem which network to connect to. Similarly, you might be connected to a Wi-Fi network or a wired network. Each is a different network but many employers would require the use of a VPN and/or a proxy service to ensure that you cannot get to places you shouldn't, cannot leak information and are protected from many forms of malware and attack.

You will probably be able to tell whether you are using a VPN assuming you can look at the network configuration. Similarly, proxies are mainly enforced in the Browser settings. It is possible, however, to configure a machine to use a hidden proxy so depending on how they configure your machine and what software they use, it may not be possible to tell. If you have access to the command line, you may be able to tell by tracing a route to a known endpoint. `tracert bbc.co.uk` for example from a Windows command line. Not always easy to interpret though.